# How to enable Intellisense in SQL Server Management Studio editor?

Tags: sql-server-2008, intellisense, ssms

Hello guys I am using SQL Server 2008 Management Studio. When I write a wrong code it should give error in the editor with red line under it like a spelling grammar in MS Word. But in my laptop I can't find this option enabled.. How to enable it?

Comment: Are you running against a **2005** engine? (see the output of `SELECT @@VERSION`). As far as I remember, these features didn't work against 2005 and earlier versions - no matter what Mgmt Studio version you have ...

Comment: The other thing that can affect SSMS intellisense is Visual Studio 2010 SP1. There is a MS support article on this http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2531482

Comment: Should I reinstall 2008 all the way and remove2005.. Is it possible to install on windows 8.1 because I am running vmware win7 installed in it.

Comment: No I don't have visual studio installed in my system

Answer (score 3):

Go to Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> Transact-SQL -> IntelliSense -> Enable IntelliSense, as shown in the snippet below.

[image]

Open New Query Window -> Go to Edit -> Expand IntelliSense -> Click Refresh Local Cache or press the shortcut key (CTRL + SHIFT + R) to refresh the local cache as shown in the snippet below.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Go to the Query tab at the top of your ssms, you can find intellisense, the shortcut is CTRL+J. If you still can't able to find then just refresh your local cache by CTRL+SHIFT+R.

Comment: Not helped... I think I have to download sql 2008 complete... Rather than just a.management studio.. As Marc_s said that it this feature didn't work against 2005._

Comment: but again if you are running against 2005, it will not work for you if you still reinstall 2008

Comment: No I have Uninstalled 2005 and now installing 2008 from scratch. Hope this help